# Binary stream '111' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change

Tags: c#, asp.net, deserialization

In our asp.net application we are implementing memcached caching technique. For this we are storing class of object serialized format and stored with key into memcache server.

While retriving we are using key and retrive the data and deserialize return back to actual class.

The error is not occurring in local machine, it is occurred in server in rare scnairo.

While **Deserialize** we face the error below,

```
Exception:Binary stream '111' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.
Stack Trace:System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Binary stream '111' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at TUtil.DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
```

The below code for serialize & Deserialize we used in our application.

```
public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object o)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
        return stream;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                
        throw;                
    }

}

public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
{
    try
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        return o;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The calling funtion for above serialize and deserialize below,

```
public static T FetchCache<T>(string Keyname)
    {
        try
        {
            mStr = (MemoryStream)mCache.Get(Keyname);
            if (mStr != null)
            {
                return (T)TUtil.DeserializeFromStream(mStr);
            }
            else { return default(T); }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }  

public static bool StoreCache<T>(string Keyname, T Obj, DateTime expirelimit)
    {
        try
        {
            mStr = TUtil.SerializeToStream(Obj);
            return mCache.Store(StoreMode.Set, Keyname, mStr, expirelimit);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Log.WriteError("StoreCache<T>(): {0}", exp);
            return false;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: What is happens with `MemoryStream` between `SerializeToStream` and `DeserializeFromStream`? Can you show [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: we use serializeToStream funtion to store the class of obj into memcached server    *mStr = TUtil.SerializeToStream(Obj);
                return mCache.Store(StoreMode.Set, Keyname, mStr, expirelimit);*   The same deserialize whenever we want from memcached server we access by using this code *mStr = (MemoryStream)mCache.Get(Keyname);*

Comment: Did you inspect the `MemoryStream` before you store it in and after receiving it from memcached? Is any difference in them (length, position or content)?

Comment: Hi @PetSerAl, I checked in local environment it working without any problem. No problem with the memorystream (length, position or content). This issue comes in live environment for some rare scnarios.

Comment: Hi@PetSerAl, As you requested i added calling funtion block of code.

Comment: @SivarajGanesan the error complains that the MemoryStream contains bad data. It may even be empty. You need to check what it contains in those cases it throws. A MemoryStream is just a wrapper around a buffer, you can retrieve it with `GetBuffer()` or check its contents in the debugger

Comment: @SivarajGanesan the error also says that the *object types* may have changed. Where does the cache store its data? Perhaps the application is trying to read data stored by an earlier version.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in local its working fine. Unable replicate in local machine. This error come in production environment. Also this error come for 1 out of 10000 request.I have a doubt this may be a data issue.